# Read AVRO messages from PubSub in Dataflow Python

Tags: python-3.x, google-cloud-dataflow, avro, google-cloud-pubsub

I have a requirement to read AVRO messages from another GCP project's PubSub topic. I have earlier implemented Python Dataflow pipelines which read JSON messages from PubSub and write to BigQuery. But I am new to handling AVRO messages. I tried to lookup Python documentation for AVRO and it points me to this link https://avro.apache.org/docs/current/gettingstartedpython.html

In this link there are examples that read from files and write to files, but I don't think these functions will be useful to read from PubSub. I am using the below transform to read from PubSub where the output is a bytestring.

```
"Read from PubSub" >> beam.io.ReadFromPubSub(topic=TOPIC).with_output_types(bytes)
```

I need a way to read these bytes(AVRO format)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Here is a sample code that you can use

1. Read Messages from Pub/Sub

```
from fastavro import parse_schema, schemaless_reader

messages = (p
            | beam.io.ReadFromPubSub(
                subscription=known_args.input_subscription)
            .with_output_types(bytes))
```

2. Use Fastavro package to define the schema and a reader via a Class definition

```
class AvroReader:
    def __init__(self, schema):
        self.schema = schema

    def deserialize(self, record):
        bytes_reader = io.BytesIO(record)
        dict_record = schemaless_reader(bytes_reader, self.schema)
        return dict_record
```

3. Now map over the byte elements and specify the schema

```
schema = avro.schema.parse(open("avro.avsc", "rb").read())
avroReader = AvroReader(schema)

lines = messages | "decode" >> beam.Map(lambda input: avroReader.deserialize(input))
```

The lines should have `PCollection` in the form of Avro.

Comment: Thanks Jayadeep for your answer. I have a question on the 'schema' variable. I have received the schema from other team as a '.avsc' file. So in this script you shared, I guess the schema be the contents of this file .avsc file. So I am trying out like this,
    

""" with open(schema_path) as fd:
        schema = json.load(fd) """

Comment: Hi Jayadeep, I did not get the last line where you are suggesting ReadFromAvro. I guess this function reads from a file. In my case the records will still come from PubSub topic.

Comment: Thanks. I will now try to create the AVRO messages and put them in PubSub so that I can test this pipeline. Currently we are dependent on other team to publish messages here. Also they have used Java. If you have the publisher code also please share here, else I will do some more searching.

Comment: Would it be something like this,

records = [
    {<record1>},
    {<record2>}]
fo = BytesIO()
writer(fo, schema, records)